# Process multiple csv files in Python / Pandas at once [Multithreading]

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, csv

I am converting a large number of csv files ( > 100 ), which are large in size ( > 1GB), into .proto files for a colleague.

On a 4gb file this is taking about 15 minutes, running ONE of my 24 threads at 100%, whilst the rest are at 0%. Wondering if there is any easy way to speed things up, either with multi-threading, or better pandas code:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("acc.csv")

    # output location
    output_file2 = path+device+'/ACC/'
    if not os.path.exists(output_file2):
        os.makedirs(output_file2)

    # open new proto file, add header
    with open(output_file2 + device + '.proto', 'wb') as f:
        header = proto.Header()
        header.deviceID = device
        header_size = header.ByteSize()
        f.write(_VarintBytes(header_size))
        f.write(header.SerializeToString())

        # for every row in the csv file, read it, convert to a protobuf message, write to file
        for i in df.index:
            time = int(float(df.get_value(i,'epoch')))
            x = float(df.get_value(i,'x'))
            y = float(df.get_value(i,'y'))
            z = float(df.get_value(i,'z'))
            acc_event = proto.AccelGyroEvent()
            acc_event.timestamp = time
            acc_event.x = x
            acc_event.y = y
            acc_event.z = z
            size = acc_event.ByteSize()
            f.write(_VarintBytes(size))
            f.write(acc_event.SerializeToString())
```

I beleive the time is taken just iterating over the 30k rows in each csv, not the actual proto converstion, so any way of speeding up would help. I tried using :

```
df.iterrows()
```

but it was marginally worse.

The data roughly looks like:

```
Device_id,   timestamp,      x,         y,         z 
7d8f7f8d7f, 189384747474, 0.847373, 0.0111233, 0.93938
```

then ~30-500k rows per file. It is being converted into a newer data format to make life easier for our research partners, specifically a proto:

```
message AccelGyroEvent {
  int64 timestamp = 1;
  float x = 2;
  float y = 3;
  float z = 4;
}
```

Comment: why are you serializing an xyz object for each row? With a repeating read+write, I'm guessing that'll be hard to improve much...unless you are reading from SSD and each process writes to its own SSD disk.

Comment: @user1269942, I think proto files need to be written like that ( ie as a data stream), but I'm not 100% sure. Writing to and from the same SSD for every file.

Comment: `iterrows()` is awful for a few reasons, its performance is one of them. That isn’t the entire program, right? Can you share some more information about the data, whether that’s an example file or a description of the format? Please see: [mcve]. We’re probably also going to need at least a basic explanation of what your program is meant to do, since I see no comments in the code you shared.

Comment: @GeordieWicks  it may be helpful to state your goal and reasons for the processing that you are doing....because at this point, I'm wondering why you don't just process the data from the csv file instead of storing it in a different format.  Is it to be consumed by something else downstream?

Comment: @user1269942, we moved from csv to proto a while ago, but have some existing data collection in csv format. We have research collaborators who have been working with the proto format, so I am just trying to unify all our data, and prevent them from having to wrangle two different data formats. The data roughly looks like:

Device_id,    timestamp,          x,             y,                  z
7d8f7f8d7f, 189384747474, 0.847373, 0.0111233, 0.93938

Comment: ok. that  makes sense, thanks for describing *why*...I will refrain from suggesting other solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since ultimately you are just saving text, maybe you can try growing a string for a while and only saving to disk(the assumption here is that the repeated disk access is the bottleneck) every so often.

your code with a couple of mods:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("acc.csv")

# output location
output_file2 = path+device+'/ACC/'
if not os.path.exists(output_file2):
    os.makedirs(output_file2)

# open new proto file, add header
with open(output_file2 + device + '.proto', 'wb') as f:
    header = proto.Header()
    header.deviceID = device
    header_size = header.ByteSize()
    f.write(_VarintBytes(header_size))
    f.write(header.SerializeToString())

    # for every row in the csv file, read it, convert to a protobuf message, write to file

    save_every = 1000 #frequency of saving...change to suit(if it works!)
    save_ix = 0  #counter
    save_str = '' #string to grow and save

    for i in df.index:
        time = int(float(df.get_value(i,'epoch')))
        x = float(df.get_value(i,'x'))
        y = float(df.get_value(i,'y'))
        z = float(df.get_value(i,'z'))
        acc_event = proto.AccelGyroEvent()
        acc_event.timestamp = time
        acc_event.x = x
        acc_event.y = y
        acc_event.z = z
        size = acc_event.ByteSize()

        #grow string, increment counter
        save_str += str(_VarintBytes(size)) #assuming _VarintBytes returns int
        save_str += acc_event.SerializeToString()
        save_ix += 1

        #save if counter is at the value 'save_every'
        if save_ix == save_every:
            f.write(save_str)
            save_ix = 0
            save_str = ''

    #save the stragglers
    if save_str != '':
        f.write(save_str)
```